# Hibernate/JPA incremental column per account

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, identifier

I'm using hibernate and i want to know if there is a good way to generate an incremental value that depends on another column. For example, `orderNumber that depends on account_id`:

```
id **orderNumber** account_id

1   1           1

2   2           1

3   1           2

4   2           2
```

I would like something like `TABLE generator` but with `pkcolumnValue` holding a dynamic value (the account_id) instead of a fixed entity name.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please try something and see what doesn't work.

Comment: Keep one table say LAST_ORDER with account_id and last_order. On Every order you have to update/save 2 tables. Try something at your end let's see what not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to keep track of the order in which the entries were added?

One potential solution to do that would be to map your entity using an @OrderColumn like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ACCOUNT")
public class Account {
    @Id @GeneratedValue @Column(name="a_id") private long id;

    @OneToMany
    @OrderColumn(name="idx")
    private List<OrderLine> orderLines;

    // other stuff
}

@Entity
@Table(name="ORDERLINE")
public class OrderLine {
    @Id @GeneratedValue @Column(name="ol_id") private long id;

    // other stuff
}
```

This will result in a table for your accounts, and one containing orderlines like this:

```
**ORDERLINE**
ol_id    a_id     idx
65473    67890    0
76843    67890    1
103473   67890    2
12563    12345    0
```

Whenever you remove an item from the list and persist, it should update the idx columns. Should you, for whatever reason, end up with gaps in the idx values, it will construct a list with NULL entries for where the gaps are. Do note that this is 0-based numbering, because it will try to enter the results back into the correct position in the java List.